# Slider issue with :first-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I just wrote a few jQuery lines to have a simple slider on a page.

I don't want this slider to loop, so I disable <kbd>PREV</kbd>/<kbd>NEXT</kbd> buttons when we reach the begin/end of the list. It works well for the <kbd>NEXT</kbd>, but I can't figure why it's not working for <kbd>PREV</kbd> (you can see the button is not disabled, even if the first element is active).

Does anybody see something I would have missed?

```js
$(function(){

    function sliderUpdate(elements) {
        $(elements).toggleClass('active');
        var active = $('#slider li.active');
        $('#slider .prev').toggleClass('disabled', active.is(':first-child'));
        $('#slider .next').toggleClass('disabled', active.is(':last-child'));
    }
    $('#slider').on('click', '.previous:not(.disabled)', function(event) {
        var toToggle = $('#slider li.active');
        toToggle = toToggle.add(toToggle.prev('li'));
        sliderUpdate(toToggle);
    });
    $('#slider').on('click', '.next:not(.disabled)', function(event) {
        var toToggle = $('#slider li.active');
        toToggle = toToggle.add(toToggle.next('li'));
        sliderUpdate(toToggle);
    });
    sliderUpdate($('#slider li').first());

});
```

```css
#slider li.active {
  color: red;
}
#slider .disabled {
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="previous">PREVIOUS</a>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is perfect, just the class name is incorrect.

```
//changed to .previous.
$('#slider .previous').toggleClass('disabled', active.is(':first-child'));
```

### Code Snippet

```js
$(function() {

  function sliderUpdate(elements) {
    $(elements).toggleClass('active');
    var active = $('#slider li.active');
    $('#slider .previous').toggleClass('disabled', active.is(':first-child'));
    $('#slider .next').toggleClass('disabled', active.is(':last-child'));
  }
  $('#slider').on('click', '.previous:not(.disabled)', function(event) {
    var toToggle = $('#slider li.active');
    toToggle = toToggle.add(toToggle.prev('li'));
    sliderUpdate(toToggle);
  });
  $('#slider').on('click', '.next:not(.disabled)', function(event) {
    var toToggle = $('#slider li.active');
    toToggle = toToggle.add(toToggle.next('li'));
    sliderUpdate(toToggle);
  });
  sliderUpdate($('#slider li').first());

});
```

```css
#slider li.active {
  color: red;
}
#slider .disabled {
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="previous">PREVIOUS</a>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
</div>
```

Comment: God... Thanks for your eyes, I guess I've been misled by the use of jQuery `prev()` function.

Answer (score 0):

//changed `.prev` to `.previous`.
$('#slider .previous').toggleClass('disabled', active.is(':first-child'));

```
  function sliderUpdate(elements) {
   $(elements).toggleClass('active');
   var active = $('#slider li.active');
   $('#slider .prev').toggleClass('disabled', active.is(':first-child'));//change in this line
    $('#slider .next').toggleClass('disabled', active.is(':last-child'));
    }
```